# How do I set the path to my Cucumber features using cucumber-junit?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I try to build my first executable specifications with Java and Maven. I created a simple project with this structure:

```
specification
|-src
  |-test
    |-java
      |-mypackage
        |-MyFeatureTest.java
    |-resources
      |-MyFeature.feature
```

In the junit test `MyFeatureTest.java` I have this:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class HomepageTest {
}
```

Now https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/wiki/IDE-support says that I should add the following line:

```
@Cucumber.Options(paths={"my/super.feature:34"})
```

I tried to modify that to

```
@Cucumber.Options(paths={"src/test/resources/"})
```

but the annotation `@Cucumber.Options` isn't available at all. My `pom.xml` has this dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.RC20</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.RC20</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Am I missing something?

**Update** I was missing something: The cucumber feature file has to be in a subdirectory `src/test/resources/mypackage/`. Otherwise it won't be picked up by the junit test.

*I can run my feature tests when I put them in the same directory `src/main/test/`, so it's not a blocker for me. But I'd like to understand the whole setup.*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861060/specify-the-feature-file-location-in-cucumber/13869842#13869842):

You can specify a location on the classpath by setting the feature attribute in the options annotation like

```
@Cucumber.Options(features="src/test/resources")
```

Edit:

in new versions code is

```
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources")
```

Answer (score 19):

The `classpath` option is not obvious in the Cucumber documentation (it is not in the JavaDoc either), I ended up inferring it from  the [CLI documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#cli-runner) (edit: link is dead, can't find an equivalent), which has other location options documented. See the  `List configuration options` section in the docs. It is also not obvious how to get the feature defintions from another module of a multi module Maven projectg.

This is what got me going (running from IDE and command line) in a Maven multi module project.

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"classpath:product"},
        //...
)
public class RunCukesTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
```

where my feature files were located in

```
main-project
    sub-module-1
        src/test/java/com/foo/
            RunCukesTest.java
        src/test/resources/product/
            feature_1.feature
            feature_2.feature
    sub-module-2
        ...
```

It pleases me not to see `src/test/resources` in the path. Note that there is no leading `/` in the path. Using the classpath is less brittle, because the classpath (rather than the current working directory) must be well defined.

Comment: This is the correct solution, all the other answers specifying 'src/test/resources' are wrong in the sense, they are brittle will only ever run correctly within an IDE.  The use of  'classpath:features' ensure this will work correctly when deployed to a CI build environment.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I suspect the accepted answer is not actually using the classpath at all. In my case we are packaging the tests in a spring-boot application. I'm hoping that using the classpath means the features can be packaged into the executable jar.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
@CucumberOptions(
    format = "pretty",
    tags = {"~@Ignore"},
    features = "src/test/resources/com/"  //refer to Feature file
)
```

for scan all of feature file in package

Comment: good suggestion since @Cucumber.Options is deprecated from version 1.1.5 ... http://xebee.xebia.in/index.php/2014/07/31/cucumber-jvm-all-you-need-to-know-about-cucumberoptions/

Comment: Thank you! Was trying @Cucumber.Options which is deprecated

Comment: Another thanks for showing the new @CucumberOptions!

Comment: How a knowledgebase remains beneficial days after it is created! After about an year, I get stuck with cucumber-scala project of mine (why not enough documentations around?), search frantically and finally reach here to learn that 'Options' is replaced with 'CucumberOptions'! Great stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I can only put this on monday morning... The directory layout I used wasn't correct, I forgot to put the cucumber features into subdirectories matching my package structure.

**Make sure you create the needed package directories also in `src/test/resources/`!**

Answer (score 1):

Once you use

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
```

You will need to add the following to your pom.xml, otherwise "mvn test" will not work. And you can only run your tests from the IDE. 
See: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/blob/master/pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.2</cucumber.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.3</maven.compiler.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just build your cucumberoptions arguments, like in https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#cli-runner described and pass it to cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(). This is a small example:

```
String arg = "classpath:MyFeature.feature --dry-run";
String[] args = arg.split(" ");
cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(args, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

and use it in you JUnit Test. So you don't have to create a seperate class for each testclass just with other arguments.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using JUnit-5 and cucumber latest (7.10) version you need to use this

```
org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectDirectories
```

E.g. `@SelectDirectories("src/test/resources")`

complete set of runner will look like this.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectDirectories("src/test/resources")
@SelectClasspathResource("yourclasspathifany")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.abc.xyz")
public class CucumberRunnerTests {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can solve this problem by adding below code snippet into your pom.xml

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

Answer (score -11):

By putting the feature file under **src/test/java** where the runner and steps file or 
by putting it under **src/main/java** the problem will get resolved.

Don't forget to say **thanks**.:)