# Specify the feature file location in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have created some cucumber test steps and a small Cucumber test case, which I run with JUnit like so:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

public class FuelCarTest {
    //executs cucumber steps in the class FuelCarSteps
}
```

The Cucumber features files are now automatically loaded from the classpath location, `src/main/resources/<package-name>/*.feature`

I could like to know how I can tell cucumber the location of my feature files, because I need it to load them from a location outside the classpath (e.g. data//).

Comment: How to specify the path of multiple feature files in CucumberOptions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution,

there is the @Cucumber.Options annotation, among setting the report output format and location, it also allows setting the location for the feature files.

```
@Cucumber.Options(
    format = {
        "pretty",
        "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
        "json-pretty:target/cucumber- report.json"
    },
    features="features/"
)
```

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to specify the feature files to run from maven command line? I'm unable to find any docs for this...

Comment: @EldadAK -D"cucumber.options=/features"

Comment: How to specify the path of multiple feature files in CucumberOptions

Comment: = { "feature1", "feature2"}

Answer (score 8):

I have placed all feature files in `test/resources/features` and added my feature file location with class path. Here is my cucumber run file.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    monochrome = true,
    features = "classpath:features",
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports",
    "json:target/cucumber.json"
             }

)
public class MyTests 
{

}
```

This will pick all feature files inside the folder features. If you want to have a subfolders you can add that too by just replacing the line as shown below.

`features = "classpath:features/DEV"`

If only one particular feature file, it should be like this

`features = "classpath:features/DEV/SmokeTests.feature"`

Comment: The `classpath` option was one that assisted me in a Maven multi module project. I ended up finding this detail (as well as other location options) in the [CLI interface documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#cli-runner).

Comment: How to specify the path of multiple feature files in CucumberOptions

Comment: Link is returning 404 (not found) error. @markdsievers

Comment: @MajidRoustaei Spent a few minutes trying to find the equivalent docs with no success I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can specify feature file from a folder, tag name and test outputs.

```
 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 @CucumberOptions(features="src/Login.feature",
    format = {"pretty", "html:target/report/",
    "json:target/report/cucu_json_report.json",
    "junit:target/report/cucumber_junit_report.xml",}
     tags ={"@ra1, @ra2"})
```

Comment: How to specify the path of multiple feature files in CucumberOptions

Answer (score 0):

You can use @CucumberOptions instead of @Cucumber.Options

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    format = "pretty",
    tags = {"~@Ignore"},
    features = "src/test/resources/com/"  //refer to Feature file
)
public class CucumberIT {  }
```

Answer (score 0):

here feature keyword for path of your feature file folder
example: my feature files folder located in desktop

so feature keyword value feature="C:\Users\sanjay\Desktop\features"

```html
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  features = "C:\\Users\\sanjay\\Desktop\\features"
  ,glue={"com.stepDefination"}
  ,monochrome = false,
    
    
    format = {"pretty", "html:target/Destination"} 
  
  )
public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: How to specify the path of multiple feature files in CucumberOptions